# How to send a stream to a SOAP server?

Tags: delphi, soap, file-upload, firemonkey

I am developing a multi platform application using RAD Studio (Firemonkey). How I can upload a file i.e. an image or an audio file or a video file to the server using Soap Web Service?

Comment: For transportation it does not matter what kind of data you send - it is just data -> a bunch of bytes. Reduce your question to "How to send a stream to a SOAP server". It is not clear if you are asking for client or server or both.

Comment: Thanks Rufo. Actually I need assistance for both server and client side coding. Can you guide me through it please?

Comment: did you read [this](http://agnisoft.com/white_papers/soapbinaryfile.asp) and [this](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/28789) ?

Comment: Thanks Rufo, It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You must define functions on server-side applications that transfer files as ByteArray. Here is [explanation](http://agnisoft.com/white_papers/soapbinaryfile.asp)

Comment: you can add this in comment section.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using Base64encoder.